How to display a given value to an input inside a form?
I'm currently working on a CV-Application project where users can give data to inputs contained in a form. When they click on “Validate”, this data stored in an array of arrays that represent school experiences then it is displayed on the side in their CV with an “Edit” button in a <li> that contains a data-attribute with a key that is the same as the React key. Clicking on Edit retrieves the data and I compare the last element of each array to find the correct array.  Once I've found it, I pass it as a boolean object to my form component. This component has a useEffect that listens and works fine when the boolean is true, and fills my state variables with the object's new data. Unfortunately, the inputs don't visually display the new values.
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import NameInputs from './NameInputs';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export default function SchoolArea({
  className,
  addSchoolExpFn,
  schoolEditionBoolean,
  dataToEdit,
  toggleEditionBoolean,
}) {
  const [school, setSchoolValue] = useState('');
  const [study, setStudyValue] = useState('');
  const [dateBegin, setDateBeginValue] = useState('');
  const [dateEnd, setDateEndValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (schoolEditionBoolean && dataToEdit) {
      console.log('Inside useEffect');
      console.log(dataToEdit.school);
      setSchoolValue(dataToEdit.school);
      setStudyValue(dataToEdit.study);
      setDateBeginValue(dataToEdit.dateBegin);
      setDateEndValue(dataToEdit.dateEnd);
    }
  }, [schoolEditionBoolean, dataToEdit]);

  const handleSchoolChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSchoolValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleStudyChange = (e) => {
    setStudyValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleDateBeginChange = (e) => {
    setDateBeginValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleDateEndChange = (e) => {
    setDateEndValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setSchoolValue('');
    setStudyValue('');
    setDateBeginValue('');
    setDateEndValue('');
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const array = [school, study, dateBegin, dateEnd, uuidv4()];
    addSchoolExpFn(array);
    e.target.reset();
    handleReset();
  };

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <NameInputs
          type="text"
          placeholder="School Name"
          value={school}
          onChange={handleSchoolChange}
        />
        <NameInputs
          type="text"
          placeholder="Studies"
          value={study}
          onChange={handleStudyChange}
        />
        <NameInputs
          type="date"
          placeholder="12/11/2024"
          value={dateBegin}
          onChange={handleDateBeginChange}
        />
        <NameInputs
          type="date"
          placeholder="13/11/2024"
          value={dateEnd}
          onChange={handleDateEndChange}
        />
        <button type="submit">Validate</button>
      </form>
      <div>
        <p>School: {school}</p>
        <p>Study: {study}</p>
        <p>Date Begin: {dateBegin}</p>
        <p>Date End: {dateEnd}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

SchoolArea.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  addSchoolExpFn: PropTypes.func,
  schoolEditionBoolean: PropTypes.bool,
  dataToEdit: PropTypes.object,
  toggleEditionBoolean: PropTypes.func,
};


How can I display the values inside a form?
EDIT : As requested, you can find below my NameInput component :
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default function NameInput({ type, placeholder, inputValue, onChange }) {
  return (
    <input
      type={type}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      value={inputValue}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
}

NameInput.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
};



What you've included looks reasonable, if the issue if the inputs not displaying their value, we'll probably need to see the code for the NameInputs component.

Kinda agree with @DBS, we need to see the NameInputs, especially, how it handles the onChange event

Your input is taking in inputValue as prop but you are passing it as value in SchoolArea component.
Also, you need to set the inputValue on the NameInput prop types

Awesome, you can vote the answer

I can't for now, don't have enough reputation, but I will try to do it later when it will be possible for me. :)
